# comparing two decaying sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, divergent-series

I have two sequences:

1. $p_0, p_0 \rho_1, p_0 \rho_2, ...$

and

2. $q_0, q_0 \gamma_1, q_0 \gamma_2, ...$.

Both sequences have infinite number of terms, and both sequences sum to 1 each. All terms are finite and non-negative. Further, I know that $\rho_1 \ge  \rho_2 \ge \rho_3...$ and $\gamma_1 \ge  \gamma_2 \ge \gamma_3...$, so all the terms in both sequences are decreasing. And, I know that $\rho_i < \gamma_i, \forall i$.

I want to say something about comparing the respective terms of the two series; i.e., how does the (say) third term of series 1 compare with the third term of series 2? It is hard to simply divide the two terms and check. Is there a smarter way?

Comment: Without knowing more about these sequences, it's pretty much impossible for us to make a sensible suggestion.  You say it's "hard" to divide and check, but what is not hard?

Comment: Couldn't we say something by looking at the rate of decay somehow?

Comment: It could be.  What do you know about the rates of decay?  You certainly haven't told us anything about them.

Comment: added a comment now, does it help?